# Android apps and server connections

Tags: android, connection, whatsapp

I am an android user and of course I use whatsapp, twitter for android, facebook and many other apps that notify me of events.
As a proogramer whats keeps me wondering is how fast notifications or whatsapp messages arrive.
My intuition tells me that is not possible for the whatsapp or twitter server to open a TCP connection with my cellphone by a given port to deliver a new message. If i am in wifi mode the router would block that connection.
And if my whatsapp client is pooling the server every second.... Poor server if it has 1000 clients making request every second.

What is the approach to face this issue?.
Is there some other protocol involved?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those apps use services that utilize "long polling" - primarily based on XMPP or some variation of XMPP (like jabber - http://www.jabber.org/). The client does not poll often. A quote for the Wiki page:

> The original and "native" transport protocol for XMPP is Transmission
>   Control Protocol (TCP), using open-ended XML streams over long-lived
>   TCP connections.

It sends a message to the server that basically is a mechanism for the server to send a message back at any time (as long as the client is available). It's like sending a request to an HTTP server and the server "time-out" does not occur for a very long time (hours), so the client just waits. If the server receives a message destined for the client, it sends a "response" to that request. After the time out does occur, the client sends another request and waits.

GCM does the same thing - but does not require you to setup servers for all portions of the connection. It's easy to search for GCM, AWS, etc. to see examples.

Answer (score 1):

Typically GCM should be used if you dont want to guarantee immediate delivery and it is okay for your app to miss out on certain messages.

This is because GCM tries to optimize by bundling several messages (even from other apps) into a single package. And it has a limited buffer to maintain the messages per device (in case the device is not reachable).

Answer (score 0):

Here is just [one way](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html) to do the job.